# How to count all elements of a certain type in a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a jQuery object of uncertain contents (from `something` that could be a dynamic selector or a string of HTML):

```
var $o = $(something);
```

Now, for example how do I count how many `<div>` objects are contained *in the jQuery object itself* (i.e. no descendants of the contained elements)? I could do

```
var l = $o.filter( function () { return $(this).is("div"); } ).length;
```

Other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.filter()` takes a selector, so

```
$o.filter('div')
```

should actually be sufficient.

And of course you could create a plugin for that:

```
$.fn.count = function(selector) {  
    return this.filter(selector).length; 
};
```

Comment: Hm. Things can be so easy sometimes. :-)

Comment: @Peter: True, but in this point, the question was not clear. But I assume that the @Tomalak already knows `find`.

Comment: Exactly. :-) (@Peter: On my part, I assumed that "contained in the jQuery object" was unambiguous. jQuery objects are arrays, not tree structures, so strictly speaking there are no descendants.)

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to count elements of a certain type within a jQuery object. Which method you use depends on your definition of `in`.

1. **[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).length** - Find all descendants of the DOM element/s represented by the jQuery object fitting a pattern. Can also use a context of the form `$(this, that)` to find this within that. It's implemented using `.find()`
2. **[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).length** - Reduce the set of selected DOM elements represented by the jQuery object to only include ones that match a pattern.

---

If you want to search for descendants in the object, use **[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** or a context:

```
$o.find("div").length
```

or

```
$("div", $o).length
```

For example

```
<li>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</li>
```

For the above:

```
$("li").find("div").length // This is 2
$("div", "li").length      // This is 2

$("li").filter("div").length // This is 0
```

---

If you want to reduce the number of selected items by a rule, use **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div></div>
```

For the above

```
$("div").filter(".a").length // This is 1

$("div").find(".a").length // This is 0
$(".a", "div").length      // This is 0
```

---

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdrWv/)** showing both `.find()` and `.filter()` at work.

Comment: Nope. I wanted to count sub-sets, not everything. ;-)